# Where to save shop cart for e-commerce website - Angular

Tags: angular, cookies, e-commerce, cart

I'am developing an online store for a client using Angular 9 as a front-end framework.
I want to keep the user's shopping cart data even after reload the page so I used browser cookies to save it. I also save Token there.
My questions are : is it a best practice to use cookies/session storage or I should save the cart in database? How to secure those data ? ( if it's good to use cookies ) ? What are the best practices to secure an e-commerce website ?

Answer (score 0):

I would say for cart store the data in database, as saving them in form of cookies or session would be bad as these can be destroyed and the customer would loose all the things they might have placed into the cart. so when a user returns after a while to his cart he will not see those items in his cart if you use session or cookies, you should use cookies and session to store info about the current user who has logged in.

Comment: Well you should also avoid storing the card data in your database. You're allowed to store only last 4 digits of the card to follow PCI-DSS standards.

Comment: @JustShadow yeah true one should do it that way but you could always use payment gateway where they wouldn't need to store card details just the transaction number rest is managed by the payment gateway service provider.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the user must be logged in to be able to store the cart data in database and make the correspondence between the cart and the user, I'm I right ? So, for the case of visitor, what i should do ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's totally a bad practice to store card info just as is, and especially in cookies.

If you want to store a card information you'll have to follow [Payment Card Industry Data Security Standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Payment_Card_Industry_Data_Security_Standard) (aka PCI-DSS). [Here](https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/document_library) is the documentation on that.

However, it usually costs much money and effort to comply with that standard.
If you're just doing a small project, you'd better use 3rd party services (like Stripe) for that.